# Increase by 1 every X seconds

Tags: javascript, counter, setinterval, increment

I'm trying to write a code that counts something like how many people have been born in a country X since the beginning of 2016. I don't have much experience coding and this is what I've come out with. Where 'd' is now and 'b' are the milliseconds until the 1st of January 2016 in Unix time. My main problem is that when the page loads, the counter doesn't appear immediately but takes full 12 seconds to appear counting.

Is there a simpler way to do this and in which the numbers load immediately? 
Thanks!

```
<span id="number"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var d = new Date();
      document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = d.getTime();
    var b = 1451606400000;
    var i = ((d - b) / 12024);
    var x = Math.round(i); 
    function increment() {
      x++;
      document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = x;
    }
    setInterval('increment()', 12024);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `x` instead of `d` on initialization:

```js
var d = new Date();
var b = 1451606400000;
var i = ((d - b) / 12024);
var x = Math.round(i); 
document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = x; // Here
function increment() {
    x++;
    document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = x;
}
setInterval(increment, 12024);
```

```html
<span id="number"></span>
```

Comment: Solved! Amazing! Thank you so much!! That was super helpful and really fast.

Comment: @DanielS no problem!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `increment` is not being called by `setInterval` until the initial 12 second delay is reached, and your `innerHTML` is not set until `increment` is called.

One solution would be to assign `x` to `innerHTML` once `x` has a proper value...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var d = new Date();
    var b = 1451606400000;
    var i = ((d - b) / 12024);
    var x = Math.round(i); 
    document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = x;
    function increment() {
      x++;
      document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = x;
    }
    setInterval(increment, 12024);
</script>
```

Comment: Solved! Amazing! Thank you so much!! That was super helpful and really fast.

Comment: Glad I could help @DanielS  :)